# Is there a difference between a "Stack Overflow profile on Careers 2.0" and a "Careers 2.0 profile"?

Tags: support, profile-page, jobs

I was overjoyed to find that I already have a profile page on Careers 2.0, which I hear is invite-only. But reading the FAQ, it seems everyone on SO have a Careers 2.0 profile, or I'm misreading something.

From the [Careers 2.0 FAQ for programmers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/faq):

> **I never signed up for this Careers 2.0 thing… why do I have a profile?**
>
> You have a **Stack Overflow profile** which is visible to anyone on the Internet (not just employers). The contents of this profile are entirely controlled by you.
>
> **What if I previously paid for membership in Stack Overflow Careers?**
>
> If you paid for the 1.0 version of Stack Overflow Careers, **your profile has automatically been upgraded to Careers 2.0** and you will have a free lifetime membership. We no longer charge any job seekers to participate.

Is there a difference between the two, and if there is, how do I find out which one I have?

Edit:

Back in Careers 1.0, I did create a CV there but can't recall paying for anything then.

Comment: It's kind of confusing to me too.  What would be the difference if I had never purchased Careers 1.0? From the text it seems like there'd be no difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your profile on StackOverflow and your profile on the Careers site are two separate entities.

Your profile on StackOverflow contains the information you see when you click your name at the top and click the edit link.  Your profile on the Careers site contains different information related to finding a job or finding people to work for you.

If you had signed up for the Careers site before we changed everything, you were grandfathered in to having a profile on the new site without having to go through the invite process.  You now have a Careers 2.0 profile.

If you had never created a CV on the Careers 1.0 site, but you meet the requirements for showing up in our passive candidate search, then the information publicly available in your StackOverflow profile is searchable in the new Careers 2.0 site.  In that case you show up as a passive candidate on the candidate search page.

Comment: I know that this is old, but what are the requirements for showing up in your passive canidate search?

Comment: @JMK there is no longer a distinction between active and passive search from the employers perspective, it's just a flag employers see when they view your profile.  All you need to show up in search is a profile on careers and then you can set yourself to passive, which does not affect your search results ranking at all.

Comment: thanks, however in that case I find myself in the same position as the op, wondering why I have a profile on an invite only site even though I was by ever invited, can you clear this up for me?

Comment: Never, not by ever, apologies!

Comment: Late Feb 2011 through sometime early this year we were creating "mini" profiles out of SO accounts who achieved certain criteria.  All of those mini profiles are set to passive search and we had a blog post informing people how to opt out.  In the case that an employer wants to contact one of these profiles, we pinged their global inbox only.

Comment: Thankyou, it was more confusion mixed with the feeling that I didn't really deserve a profile on such a site but thanks for clearing this up!