# How to get "Careers 2.0 profile" link in SO profile?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, jobs, profile-page

I noticed that in [Matt Sherman's SO profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70613/matt-sherman), he has a link to "Careers 2.0 profile" underneath the "Network profile" link. Unfortunely, I can't find any setting, either on SO or on SOC, that would enable showing that link for my profile. Has anyone else stumbled across such a thing?

Comment: Perhaps a symptom of this: [Is there a difference between a “Stack Overflow profile on Careers 2.0” and a “Careers 2.0 profile”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80646/is-there-a-difference-between-a-stack-overflow-profile-on-careers-2-0-and-a-ca) Do you have a Careers 2.0 profile?

Comment: @Cody: Yes, it's at http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cky :-)

Comment: Existing feature request for just such a capability: [Option to link SO user page to careers profile](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91557/option-to-link-so-user-page-to-careers-profile).

Comment: @Rick: This post isn't quite the same as what you linked: the feature is _already_ there (and so I'm not making a feature request); it's just a question of how to enable it. :-)

Comment: @Chris: Right, I didn't say it was a duplicate.  If that [feature-request] is [feature-complete] it should be tagged that way and how to enable it should be documented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a feature that we were experimenting with some time back. We decided not to go forward with it for the time being -- it was an oversight that it was left on my profile.

Comment: It's very unfortunate that it was discontinued, as I would have found it very useful. :-) Nonetheless, it's good to hear an official answer on this, so thanks. :-)